# bool value setting only execute once? then return to false in void

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

why my bool value setting only execute once? then return to false? when I perform the function it, is set to "true" once, then return to false.

```
private bool[] set = new[] { false, false, false, false};

void Update()
    {
        movefunc(setSpineRotates[0], "spinerotatecolor");
    }
 void movefunc(bool set, string co)
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            Touch screentouch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(screentouch.position);
            if (screentouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo))
                {
                    if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent(co) != null)
                    {
                        set = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Debug.log(set);
        //. when i perform the function it, set to "true" once,then return to false.
        if (set)
        {
            sliderx.SetActive(true);
            slidery.SetActive(true);
            sliderz.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

so when i perform the function, does it only copies the value?

Comment: why does `set = true;` even compile¿? -> `Cannot implicilty convert type bool to bool[]`

Comment: @rustyBucketBay no in OP's method there is also the parameter `bool set` which is hiding the outer `bool[] set` ..

Comment: oh, very true. Thanks

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is in `c#` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When bool type is passed to a function, it does not passed by reference.
A new instance of that bool is created, and in that function, only that instance is changed to true.

To fix that you need either pass it with ref keyword, or use the index[i] as the parameter like so:

```
void movefunc(int index, string co)
{
    ...
    if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent(co) != null)
    {
        set[index] = true;
    } 
}
```